# Quickly Generate a Unique, Static Token for a Model

Tags: python, django

I have a few models for which I want to generate unique tokens so I can access them using a "secret" URL. Right now I'm doing that by creating a "token" field on each model and populating in the model's `save` method using `uuid`, like this:

```
        self.token = uuid.uuid4().hex
        while Notification.objects.filter(token=self.token).exists():
            self.token = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

While this works, the obvious drawbacks are that (1) I need to have a `token` field for every `Notification` entry and, more importantly, (2) this queries the database at least once every time I create a new model.  While it's highly unlikely that uuid4() will produce a duplicate token, any serious application still needs to make that check.

Is there a better way I can generate a random unique token, perhaps derived from the model's id, that I can be guaranteed is unique but is still not predictable/guessable to an attacker without having to make a query to ensure that it's unique?

Comment: I have the same problem and am doing the exact same thing, except I'm using `from django.utils import crypto, crypto.get_random_string(field_length)`. I don't see how one can create something random and know it's not a repeat without checking.

Answer (score 1):

Add a constraint to make sure the token field only accepts unique values. Then catch the exception in the save method and regenerate a token if it is.

`unique=True` on the field.

Answer (score 0):

you perhaps want something along the lines of [itsdangerous](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/), or simply the standard [hmac](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hmac.html) library

The idea is that you would establish a private secret key on your server;  You need do this only once.

Then, use that secret key, along with an apropriate hashing algorithm to generate what's called a "message authentication code", which is a secure means of proving that a message is really, honestly from the original source, in your case, from your server.  The message would contain the primary key or some other useful query value for the data you want to access.

when responding to a request for one of these, you decompose the message into the lookup value and signature, and verify that the signature is for that particular value.

One disadvantage is that the primary key (or other key) is encoded in clear text in the message; which could possibly disclose more information about the object than you'd like.  That said, there's no (reasonable) possibility that the signature can be "guessed" for any particular key, without the signing key.